# Interpolating the Tutte polynomial at the values of two hyperbolas

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, planar-graphs, integer-programming

In [a MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173259/what-is-the-probability-of-interpolating-the-tutte-polynomial-of-a-planar-graph)
basically I asked when the Tutte polynomial of planar graph
can be uniquely determined by the polynomially computable values at the special points
and at the two hyperbolas. The solution is the unique solution
of certain integer program $L$. Possibly misleading experimental
data suggests this is possible sometimes.

Computing the Tutte polynomial at non-trivial points
is $\#P$-complete. In case the integer program $L$
has unique solution, one call to a $NP$-complete
oracle would solve $\#P$-complete problem.

> In case this happens, what are the complexity
>   implications for the subclass of planar graphs
>   satisfying this?

Suppose the integer program $L$ has polynomially many solutions corresponding
to polynomials $F_{G,i}(x,y)$. (The experimental data
suggest this).

> Given $G$ and a set of polynomials $F_{G,i}$ with
>   the promise that one of them is the Tutte polynomial,
>   what is the complexity of finding the Tutte polynomial?

AFAICT it is not harder than $\#P$ since we can compute
the Tutte polynomial at positive random $(x_i,y_i)$ and
see which of $F_{G,i}$ agree with the value.